# Can my parents from MI give me a car in MD? What is the cheapest way of dealing with it?

Tags: vehicle, michigan, maryland

I live in Maryland(MD) and my parents just bought a car for me in Michigan(MI). However first I don't have a title claim on the car let alone an insurance. Is it possible for me to get a temporary plate from MD, go to MI, staple that in and drive the car back?

So to get that plate from MD I have to apply for car title, which would take ~2 weeks. Can my parents just send me their title signed through mail and I can sign it in MD or is the car title only valid in MI and I have to get a temporary MI plate to drive that car back to MD? And how does this work for gifts? Do my parents declare $0 cost on the car in the title?

Thank you

Comment: They must have a MI title - do they also have a MI plate?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite They have the title. No they don't have a plate

Comment: Would it make sense for them to get plates in MI, you drive it to MD and then they gift it to you. You can legitimately drive it while the title and plates are in the works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some searching I found out this link: https://mva.maryland.gov/vehicles/Pages/registration/title-registration-info.aspx#transfer-gift

In here there is a last section as follows:

> All other transfers as gifts are subject to the state inspection laws.
> Gifts of vehicles that are titled out-of-state are not accepted.

So it seems I have to have the title under my name before I get it registered in MD.

Comment: I'm not sure about gifting in MI, but it took no time at all when I did it MD (the MD form had a required transaction fee, so the person giving it to me settled a $10 debt they owed me for another matter.  Legally I bought a car for $10 bucks in MD, but we didn't enforce small debts like that between us, so it was just a number we wrote).

Comment: The quoted text merely indicates that you normally don't have to get the vehicle inspected if the transfer is between spouses or parent and child. It has nothing to do with title and registration. What the last sentence really means is that because the vehicle is coming from out of state, it has never been inspected in Maryland, so it needs to be inspected even though it is a transfer from parent to child.

Comment: The full quote: "If a vehicle is being transferred between spouses or between parents and children, an inspection is not generally required. All other transfers as gifts are subject to the state inspection laws. Gifts of vehicles that are titled out-of-state are not accepted."